# About open comment in my web site

Tags: php, facebook

In my web application in PHP users need to enter comments using their facebook authentication . I need to show users name in my web site. But the comments must save in my local db..

Is there is any way for that ?

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, using the JavaScript API, you can get their ID.. Grab their FB info (like Name), and store their FBID and NAME into your own DataBase. You will have to write your own Comment stream, of course.

Comment: thanks for your comments and if you dont mind can you please specify the plugin ?